# Firefox: Why is my font bold and italic?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, fonts

I use duckduckgo a lot and recently the font that shows up on duckduckgo is bold and italic. Actually, the font when entering the title of this question is bold and italic.

I hate that font. Why is it doing that? Any ideas on how to fix it?

I'm using Windows 7 and Firefox 9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

In the Firefox menu, under Tools -> Options is where you can change the default font.

[image]